# Passing Messages with PID to Erlang from Python using ErlPort

Tags: python, erlang

I would like to pass a message from python to Erlang in the `{From(PID}, atom}` format, because my erlang program needs to know which process id to send a message to.

Erlang Message Loop:

```
message_loop([First | Rest]) -> 
receive 
    {From, ready} ->
        % From ! {self(), {read, First}},
        python:cast(From, {read, First}),
        message_loop(Rest);
    {From, done} ->
        python:cast(From, {read, First}), 
        message_loop(Rest);
    {From, _} ->
        io:format("Invalid Message Received From");
    _ ->
        io:format("Random Message")
end.
```

How do I pass such a message, using ErlPort? Or is there any other technique I can use to communicate selectively to a process after spawning many of them?

Comment: Did you read the documentation http://erlport.org/docs/python.html ? Did that work?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in documented [types mapping](http://erlport.org/docs/python.html#data-types-mapping) there is no option to do it automatically.

What you could do is translate `PID` into string representation with `erlang:pid_to_list/1`, send this to python.  And when receiving from python you could use `erlang:list_to_pid/1`. That should work good enough.